# Ipython 3.0.0 html not exported to pdf

Tags: html, pdf, export, jupyter-notebook

Just upgraded my IPython to the new stable release 3.0.0 on Debian Linux, after the first few bumps i'm now able to export my notebooks to pdf ...

However ... when html is used the html isn't rendered to pdf by nbconvert.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
eersteWaarde = 3.2
tweedeWaarde = 4.3

s = """<table width="80%">
<tr>
    <th width="40%">Eerste waarde</th>
    <th width="40%">Tweede waarde</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>""" + str(eersteWaarde) + """</td>
    <td>""" + str(tweedeWaarde) + """</td>
</tr>
</table>"""

html = HTML(s)
display(html)
```

This shows up in notebook as a table as intended but when de notebook is exported to pdf the table is not rendered, the pdf document shows  instead.

All other items like Images and Latex are rendered to pdf just like the manual says, so i'm thinking my installation misses a plug-in or something of the sort.

The output of nbconvert is attached for your reference ...

```
%%bash 
ipython nbconvert Untitled1.ipynb --to pdf

[NbConvertApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/wout/.ipython/profile_default'
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook Untitled1.ipynb to pdf
[NbConvertApp] Support files will be in Untitled1_files/
[NbConvertApp] Loaded template article.tplx
[NbConvertApp] Making directory Untitled1_files
[NbConvertApp] Writing 15864 bytes to notebook.tex
[NbConvertApp] Building PDF
[NbConvertApp] Running pdflatex 3 times: [u'pdflatex', u'notebook.tex']
[NbConvertApp] PDF successfully created
[NbConvertApp] Making directory Untitled1_files
[NbConvertApp] Writing 206123 bytes to Untitled1.pdf
```

Also, where would I find the intermediate file 'notebook.tex'? BTW. html cellmagic is also not rendered correctly when exported to pdf.

Any help would be great,
KK

Answer (score 0):

Converting arbitrary HtML to Latex is probably not possible. SO there is no effort to bring HTML in PDF conversion. SO HTML is dropped on purpose in conversion process.